# Custom domain in free tier on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

Is there any way to map EC2 instance on a custom domain I own within free tier of AWS? I used it once with Route53 but I got charged, so I know it is paid. I could not find any docs for the same. Is Route53 the only way to map domain to EC2 instance on AWS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can map a domain using an external DNS management service(E.g Google DNS, Godaddy) by mapping a CName record set to the public DNS issued by the EC2 instance.

> Public DNS (IPv4)
>   ec2-54-93-211-192.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

You can find the auto-generated public DNS in EC2 web console after selecting the EC2 instance. Also it is recommended to associate and Elastic IP and then use the new public DNS for the CName mapping so that, the public DNS won't change in between EC2 stop and start.

Comment: Hey thanks @Ashan. Can you give me any good source from where I can learn just a starting bit about these things? CNAME, A records, DNS, etc.

Comment: Check the following, seems it explains https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/differences-between-a-cname-alias-url/

Answer (score 2):

You should find that your AWS account also includes access to Amazon Lightsail, which gives you your first 3 DNS zones and up to 3 million DNS queries at no charge, if you create them from the Lightsail portal rather than creating them directly in Route 53.

The Lightsail DNS service is still powered by Route 53.  It doesn't have as many advanced features as the paid version, but is quite suitable for basic sites.

See https://amazonlightsail.com/docs/.

Comment: Amazon Lightsail is free for only three months. Source: https://aws.amazon.com/pt/free/compute/lightsail/

Comment: @LucianoBrum you're speaking of the 3 month free compute/database/container tiers, but this is separate.  From the [Lightsail FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/faq/): *Q: What does Lightsail DNS management cost?* ***DNS management is free within Lightsail. You can create up to 3 DNS zones and as many records as you want for each DNS zone. You also get a monthly allowance of 3 million DNS queries per month to your zones. Beyond your first 3 million queries in a month, you are charged $0.40 USD/million DNS queries.***